# Condensation/moisture on AC Unit

Tags: air-conditioning, central-air

Is there any particular reason why there is so much moisture/condensation coming from this AC unit?
[image]

Added context: it rained the entire day before this photo was taken, but the unit is located underneath a deck. Furthermore, there is a piece of corrugated metal above the unit to prevent rain from falling on it.

Comment: @jsotola: so, is it your opinion that the water is not from the unit?

Comment: There should be a pvc  drain about 1 inch you could add on to it and divert the water away from the door on to the grass .

Comment: Coming out of that retaining wall behind the unit?

Comment: As for the drain  it should be a condensate trap drain with out it unit both sucks and blows air. and water sits and drains when the unit shuts off

Comment: Ya  if pad is touching wall  could see that looks like old stain

Comment: https://www.conditionedairsolutions.com/water-around-air-conditioners-outside-unit/. This was a good read

Comment: @Kris this is exactly the information I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

Moisture or condensation is a normal part of an AC system, the outside unit only has a little area that be cold, the larger line into the compressor is the suction line this line should be insulated as it will sweat and drip when the system is running, very little of the suction line should be exposed. The part that really generates the water is the inside unit. This is where the cooled high pressure Freon is released to low pressure by an orifice or thermostatic valve. This creates cold and pulled the moisture out of the air the moisture drips into a tray and is drained into the house water drains or outside which ever is easily done. In a humid climate , just after a rain the inside unit can easily create 10 gallons a day on a 5 ton system and this may be the source of the water if draining outside on the pad. The outside unit if creating very much at all needs more or some insulation added and this will increase efficiency saving $ and reducing moisture from the outside unit.